# Javascript math "draw" rectangles around multiple other rectangles to achieve backdrop effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, position

Note: I will use the word *overlay* interchangeably with *backdrop*.

I'm currently working on a guide mode and I highlight elements to make them stand out from the darker semi-transparent background.

So basically, I have a selector for the element that I want to not be overlaid, and then I surround it with semi-transparent dark divs, simulating an overlay with an excluded element.

My solution works great for one highlighted element, but when that number becomes 2+, it becomes hard to calculate how to place the black divs around those elements. And the thing is: The highlight needs will vary significantly from page to page - it's not like those multiple elements will be static.

So to illustrate my issue:

[image]

Here you can see the different boxes that need to be put into the page in order to surround Box2 and Box2 with the semi-transparent dark divs, basically simulating the overlay effect with highlighted elements. For one case like this one, I can *hardcode* the calculations and everything would be fine, but **what if** Box1 was higher up than Box2? Then what if they were not overlapping each other horizontally anymore? What if there is a Box3 that needs highlighting?

In either case, I wouldn't know how many dark boxes to place and where to place them.

Is there any mathematical formula that would help me in this case? The use of jQuery is also possible as it's included in my project.

How would I approach this problem and make it extendable (multiple boxes, different positions)?

Comment: Write a function which subtracts a rectangle from another, creating a list of smaller rectangles in return. Now, apply that function to the bounding box and the first highlighted rectangle. Then, apply that function to each of the rectangles returned from the previous call. Rinse and repeat. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry for more optimal algorithms

Comment: Hey! I submitted a working solution, can you take a look at it?

Comment: What you're really looking for is what's called a _Region_ data type. Regions perform union/intersection/subtraction on rectangularly-bounded chunks of 2-D space, and are designed so you can readily construct them from Rectangles and deconstruct Rectangles from them. I've written the code in C to do this before, and it's complicated in the general case. Most GUIs natively include a Region type (Windows, X, and Mac all have it) and use it for most rendering, but there doesn't seem to be a JavaScript implementation that I can find: Surprisingly, no NPM package seems to be available to do this.

Answer (score 9):

You're overthinking!
What you are looking for can be achieved with a certain HTML and CSS layout.

You have to use a layout similar to this:

```
.container
    .overlay
    .box
    .box
    .box
    .box
```

The trick is to use a *full-width, semi-transparent overlay* and bring elements that need to be highlighted to front. Very important thing is to assign `pointer-events: none` to the overlay so you can click through it!

Make `.box` have a `z-index` value of, say, `1` and `.overlay` have a `z-index` value of `100`. In order to highlight a certain `.box`, set its `z-index` to `101`. That way it will appear highlighted.

I'm on mobile right now, but I put a basic proof-of-concept on <kbd>[Codepen](http://codepen.io/weary_adventurer/pen/ZKXvVM)</kbd>. Click on boxes to highlight them, click again to undo. Works with multiple boxes!

Comment: This works nicely! Just to be "that guy" though, depending on what your minimum supported target is, keep in mind that IE 10 and under doesn't support the `pointer-events' property.

Comment: @JonathanBowman Thanks for the feedback! I am aware of this and there is a IE-specific hack involving `\9` iirc. OP haven't said anything about browser support so I assume it's not a problem. In fact, OP haven't said anything **at all**, perhaps he doesn't want to give away the bounty :D

Comment: Haha, well let's hope that isn't the case :) I'll need to check out that hack, because pointer-events is really useful but I know some companies (like the one I work for), still have customers on IE 9 to worry about. And yeah you're absolutely right he didn't mention client support, I just know sometimes you get bitten by things like that, so I wanted to chime in. Thanks for the tip on the workaround though, I'll look it up!

Comment: An alternative could be to have "base overlay"->box->box overlay.  All of the boxes are on top of the overlay and have their own overlay sized to exactly cover the box.  When you select, that overlay disappears.  Gets around pointer events needing to pass through

Comment: @LaplieAnderson So kinda like a small overlay for each box? Might do the job as well, but not as effective as single overlay solution. Pointer events are supported in all major browsers, and if you really need to support deprecated browsers there was a hack for legacy browsers iirc. If your clients use such browsers though, you might think about switching to CSS2.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this solved more easily using a shadow.

Then , you only need to segment the screen in 2 parts

```css
body, html {
   height: 100%; 
 }

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, yellow, tomato);
}
.mask {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%; 
    height: 100%; 
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#mask1 {
    left: 0px;
}

#mask2 {
    right: 0px;
}

.hole {
    width: 150px; 
    height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#mask1 .hole {
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
}

#mask2 .hole {
    left: 140px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask" id="mask1">
    <div class="hole"></div>
</div><div class="mask" id="mask2">
    <div class="hole"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Consider Using Regions**

While there are a number of good answers here, and you might want to consider moving the elements like @WearyAdventurer proposed, none of the other answers actually address the original question:

> *How do I create elements in such a way that they appear to surround other elements?*

The answer to that question is best solved using a data type called a *Region*.  Regions allow you to easily perform set operations using chunks of 2-D screen space:  Combine *this* area with *that* area and then subtract *another* area, and then turn the result into a set of rectangles I can render.   Regions exist in most window systems (MS Windows, X Windows, classic MacOS, among others), and are used heavily in most browsers' internal mechanics for rendering elements, but they're surprisingly absent in JavaScript.

Or they were absent until I wrote a library to do it.

The underlying logic of regions is somewhat complicated.  There are many corner cases, and handling all the scenarios that can arise can be challenging.  My implementation, [Region2D](https://seanofw.github.io/region2d/), uses disjoint rows (bands) of disjoint rectangles (1-dimensional regions), which is the same way that many X Windows servers do it.  Other implementations use spacial partitioning algorithms, and still others (like modern MacOS) use pathing or polygon-rendering techniques instead of regions altogether.

---

**The Basic Idea**

Regardless of which implementation you use, the basic idea remains the same.  In your case, you start with a big rectangle that covers the screen, and then simply subtract away the two (or three, or four, or whatever) rectangles you want, and then ask the region which rectangles result from those operations.  In JavaScript, using my Region2D library, it looks like this:

```
var screenRegion = new Region([0, 0, viewportWidth, viewportHeight]);
var elemRegion1 = new Region(element1);
var elemRegion2 = new Region(element2);
var coverRegion = screenRegion.subtract(elemRegion1).subtract(elemRegion2);
var coverRectangles = coverRegion.getRects();
```

The resulting array of rectangles are simple objects that have `x` / `y` / `width` / `height` / `top` / `left` / `right` / `bottom` coordinates, so you just create `<div>` elements from each one, and you're done.

---

**Working Implementation**

So here's a working implementation of a solution to the actual problem as presented, using my Region2D library to do the heavy algorithmic lifting:

```js
// Generate regions for each of the objects.
var containerRegion = new Region2D($(".container")[0]);
var target1Region = new Region2D($(".target1")[0]);
var target2Region = new Region2D($(".target2")[0]);

// Subtract the targets from the container, and make an array of rectangles from it.
var coverRegion = containerRegion.subtract(target1Region).subtract(target2Region);
var coverRects = coverRegion.getRects();

// Create gray <div> elements for each rectangle.
for (var i = 0, l = coverRects.length; i < l; i++) {
    var coverRect = coverRects[i];
    var coverElement = $("<div class='cover'>");
    coverElement.css({
        left: (coverRect.x - 1) + "px", top: (coverRect.y - 1) + "px",
        width: coverRect.width + "px", height: coverRect.height + "px"
    });
    coverElement.appendTo($(".container"));
}
```

```css
.container, .target1, .target2, .cover { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
.target1, .target2 { border: 1px solid red; }
.container { width: 330px; height: 230px; border: 1px solid blue; }
.target1 { top: 40px; left: 40px; width: 100px; height: 80px; }
.target2 { top: 100px; left: 180px; width: 100px; height: 80px; }
.cover { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border: 1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/region2d@1.0.0/plain/region2d.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="target1"></div>
    <div class="target2"></div>
</div>
```